# Remove duplicated based on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a flights table that consists of few columns but somebody seem to have ran a migration twice that resulted in creation of same data twice.

Anyway, the flight should only have only data from the following condition: The flight_number and the date.
Basically the table is looking like this at the moment:

| flight_number | date |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-09-16 |
| 123 | 2021-09-16 |
| 123 | 2021-09-17 |
| 124 | 2021-09-18 |
| 124 | 2021-09-18 |

Result I want:

| flight_number | date |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-09-16 |
| 123 | 2021-09-17 |
| 124 | 2021-09-18 |

Basically, keep only one and remove duplicated (if the flight_number is same of the same date).

I'm looking for a DELETE SQL query but couldn't find the one like I am looking for.
What is the query that can help me achieve it?
Thanks!

EDIT: Yes, all the data has a column `id` that is unique even if the data is same.

Comment: Check this answer. This may help to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Comment: ```select flight_number, date from table group by  flight_number, date```

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify which rows to keep and which to remove; this can be done as such:

```
delete ff from 
flight ff
inner join (


select flight_number, row_number() over (partition by flight_number order by date) as RN
from flight f

) dups
on ff.flight_number = dups.flight_number
where dups.rn > 1
```

Basically, this uses Row_Number to create a row identifier based on certain criteria, in this case, for each (partition) Flight_number, create a row number then delete any records where the row_number is > 1.

You will need to change this to use the *actual* ID column on the join, like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=58a4ac7235ea22b557116ad68c8449c3

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on MySQL 5.7